Is there a substructure-preservation result for FOL in finite model theory?
It's well-known$^*$ that the Los-Tarski theorem ("Every substructure-preserved sentence is equivalent to a $\forall^*$-sentence") fails for $\mathsf{FOL}$ in the finite setting: we can find a first-order sentence $\varphi$ such that $\varphi$ is not equivalent to any $\forall^*$-sentence even when we restrict attention to finite models, but if $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi$ is finite and $\mathfrak{B}\subseteq\mathfrak{A}$ then $\mathfrak{B}\models\varphi$.
I'm curious about whether there is anything that could be called a substructure preservation theorem for $\mathsf{FOL}$ in finite model theory:

Is there a computable set of first-order sentences $\Phi$ with the following properties?

Whenever $\varphi\in\Phi$ and $\mathfrak{A}\supseteq\mathfrak{B}$ are finite structures, we have $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi\implies\mathfrak{B}\models\varphi$.

Every $\varphi$ satisfying the previous bulletpoint is equivalent over finite structures to some $\psi\in\Phi$.



If the answer is no, can we at least have some such $\Phi$ which is not $\Pi^0_1$-complete? (Since the set of substructure-preserved-in-the-finite sentences is $\Pi^0_1$, this is the weakest nontriviality notion I can think of.)

$^*$This is a really cute argument that I just learned. The key point is that if $B$ is a complete Boolean algebra with set of atoms $X$, then first-order logic over $B$ can implement monadic second-order logic over $X$ ... and every finite Boolean algebra is trivially complete.
Now consider the sentence $\theta$ in the language $\{\le, s\}$ that says

$\le$ yields a Boolean algebra (construed as a poset in the usual way);

$s$ is not always the identity but $s(x)=x$ for every nonatomic $x$; and

$s$ cyclically permutes the atoms ("the only $s$-closed subsets of $X$ are $X$ and $\emptyset$").


This last bulletpoint isn't obviously first-order, but it is monadic second-order over the set of atoms so we're fine per the above. If $\mathcal{M}\models\theta$ and $\mathcal{N}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{M}$, then $\mathcal{N}$ must contain all or none of the original atoms of $\mathcal{M}$, and in the latter case we won't have $\mathcal{N}\models\theta$. So now let $\varphi$ be any $\{\le\}$-sentence not equivalent to a universal sentence, and consider $\varphi\wedge\theta$.

@bof See my edit! Interestingly, while this basic idea kills most preservation theorems in the finite setting, the homomorphism preservation theorem holds: see Rossman.

Is there a counterexample without function symbols?

Do you know if there is a sentence which is preserved, in the finite setting, by homomorphs, substructures and direct products, but is not equivalent to a universally quantified conjunction of atomic formulas?

@bof No idea. Given how badly preservation theorems usually fail for finite FOL I suspect the answer is yes, but I have no real reason to believe that.

@bof Oops, sorry - your second comment. I think we can modify the example in my post to work without function symbols; just augment the sentence with "If $R$ is the graph of a function then ..." appropriately, so that the sentence descends vacuously to substructures we don't want.

Does that work? Can't a model of $\neg\theta$ be embedded in a larger structure which satisfies $\theta$ "vacuously" because $R$ is no longer the graph of a function?

@bof Yes, sorry, that's garbage. I'll revisit this in the morning, it's a good question!

A class of finite structures is closed under passage to substructures iff it's the class of all finite models of some set of universal sentences, but that's trivial and doesn't help with your question.

Duh. By "closed under passage to substructures" I meant "closed under substructures and isomorphisms.

@bof Wait, isn't every collection of structures closed under isomorphism? :P :D
